Flink SQL CDC connector do nothing to the setting "debizum.*" when create the source table
I have following table in the souce database:
CREATE TABLE `client_test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

Becasue some reason I need only partial data in this table for the snapshot so I define the Flink stream table as follow:
CREATE TABLE client_cdc (
    id DOUBLE,
    name VARCHAR(500),
    age DOUBLE,
    PRIMARY KEY(id) NOT ENFORCED
)
WITH (
    'connector' = 'mysql-cdc',
    'hostname' = 'mariadb',
    'port' = '3306',
    'username' = 'ooo',
    'password' = 'ooo',
    'database-name' = 'xxx',
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'initial',
    'table-name' = 'client_test',
    'debezium.snapshot.query.mode' = 'custom',
    'debezium.snapshot.select.statement.overrides' = 'xxx.client_test',
    'debezium.snapshot.select.statement.overrides.xxx.client_test' = 'SELECT * FROM xxx.client_test WHERE id > 3'
);


I try do filter out the rows which id is less than 3 when sanpshot. But after execute select * from client_cdc; in flink client I can still see all the sanpshot.
I also try to run this:
CREATE TABLE client_cdc (
    id DOUBLE,
    name VARCHAR(500),
    age DOUBLE,
    PRIMARY KEY(id) NOT ENFORCED
)
WITH (
    'connector' = 'mysql-cdc',
    'hostname' = 'mariadb',
    'port' = '3306',
    'username' = 'ooo',
    'password' = 'ooo',
    'database-name' = 'xxx',
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'initial',
    'table-name' = 'client_test',
    'debezium.snapshot.query.mode' = 'custom',
    'debezium.snapshot.select.statement.overrides' = 'xxx.client_test',
    'debezium.snapshot.select.statement.overrides.xxx.client_test' = 'this should failed SELECT * FROM xxx.client_test WHERE id > 3'
);


Here in 'debezium.snapshot.select.statement.overrides.xxx.client_test' I give an invaild query but I can still execute select * from client_cdc; and it still take a full snapshot. In other word it seems to me the Flink CDC connector is ignoring the settings are Prefix debezium.*
Am I missing anything here?
[MySQL Flink CDC Connector]
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-cdc-docs-master/docs/connectors/flink-sources/mysql-cdc/#connector-options
Expect to see only rows filter in debezium.snapshot.select.statement.overrides.[database].[tale]
ex: SELECT * FROM xxx.client_test WHERE id > 3 I should only see id is greater than 3 after the snapshot in the stream table even I have id less than 3 in the table in mysql database.
